# How do i do a simple php email sending?

Tags: php, eclipse, email

As stated in subject.

How do i do it? I'm doing it on Eclipse Galileo using php.

Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

Just like this:

```
mail('to@email.com', 'subject', 'message body');
```

See the php [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation for more advanced usage.

Comment: Hi i would like to do it inside a button. How do i do it?



<input type="text" id="search" name="search"/><input type="submit" value="search" name="search"/>

Comment: Have the button post to the PHP page that your mail code is on.

Comment: @cheesebunz - Set your form tag's `action` attribute to the path of your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php mail function simply. But I would suggest you to use [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/). PHPMailer library has lots of options. You can set attachment, message as text or html, bcc, cc, reply to very easily.